# $(S^1 \times [0,1])/\sim$ homeomorphic to unit disk $ D^2$

Tags: general-topology

Let $\sim$ be the equivalence relation on $S_1 \times I$ given by $(x,t)\sim(y,s)$ if and only if $xt=ys$
where $I=[0,1]$

How do I prove that $(S_1 \times I)/\sim$ is homeomorphic to the unit disk $D^2$ with the induced topology?

Comment: Have you tried to draw something? Note that $(x,0)\sim (y,0)$ for all $x,y\in S_1$. (Intuitively, the base is reduced to one single point) This is the only non-trivial equivalence class. (Prove it!) Now try to create a homeomorphism taking $S_1\times\{t\}$ to concentric circles (subsets of $D^2$).

Comment: Will the single point be (0,0)? To create a homeomorphism, do you think this works f:(a,b)-->a*(b+ 1/n)  (since b=(0,0)) ? thanks in advance

Comment: No, it can't be that point because $(0,0)\not\in S_1\times I$, but I can certainly see why you think that (It's the intuition working) :)  What you have is the equivalence class $[(p,0)]$ with all the elements of the base $S_1\times\{0\}$, not an "external point". That homeomorphism doesn't work because we don't know what $n$ is. Bear in mind the concentric circles around $(0,0)\in\Bbb R^2$ are of the form $tS_1=\{tp:p\in S_1\}$ with $t$ fixed. ;)

Answer (score 4):

The map $f:S^1×I→D^2$ which maps $(x,s)$ to $xs$ is continuous, closed, and surjective as each $y\ne 0\in D^2$ is the image of $\left(\frac y{||y||},||y||\right)$. Since $f(x,s)=f(y,t)\iff xs=yt\iff (x,s)\sim (y,t)$, the universal property of quotient spaces induces a homeomorphism $\dfrac{S^1×I}\sim \to D^2$

Comment: I have edited the last TeX code, since it seems you missed an arrow, or a $\simeq$ sign.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: Thanks :-)